# Trying to set the cursor position inside a textbox after updating the model object

Tags: angular, textbox, cursor-position, ngmodel

I want to set the cursor position after changing the model object but it actually tries to set the cursor position before updating the value of the textbox.

HTML:

```html
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" [(ngModel)]="myString">
    <button type="button" (click)="updateText('testStr')">
```

TS:

```js
    myTextBox: HTMLInputElement;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.myTextBox = document.getElementById('test');
    }

    updateText(str:String){
    this.myString+=str;
    this.myTextBox.focus();
    this.myTextBox.setSelectionRange(2,2);
    }
```

This way, because it tries to set the cursor position before actually updating the text, it can only `focus()`. But, if I don't bind anything to the textbox and update its text by doing `this.myTextBox.setAttribute('value',str);` and then `focus()` and call `setSelectionRange` it works. What should I do?

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931845/angular2-keyup-event-update-ngmodel-cursor-position-jumps-to-end

Comment: you  can use ngModelChange and ngModelOption on blur to do the focus part read more in article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
updateText(str:String){
    this.myString+=str;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.myTextBox.focus();
        this.myTextBox.setSelectionRange(2,2);
    },0);
}
```